# How do I write $\csc$ and $\tan$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to write $\csc$ and $\tan$ and terms of classical trigonometric functions like $\sin$ and $\cos$. I know about the identity $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$. But I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What do you mean by $\tan$ and/or $\csc$?

Comment: A [Google search for trigonometric identities](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigonometric+identities) brings up many results, including [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).  Among the identities listed on Wikipedia are the [definitions of the trig functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Trigonometric_functions), which include the identities you seek (e.g. $\csc(\theta) = 1/\sin(\theta)$).  Please do some basic research before asking a question here.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following identity relating the cosecant to the sine:
$$\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$

Similarly, you have

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

relating the tangent to sine and cosine. These are the classics, but since the trigonometric functions all have interesting relationships among each other, you may transform these to various other identities.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan x=\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac {\pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{\cos x}$$
for example.  There a number of forms.  Which one you want depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

$\csc x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$ and $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ by definition.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! Note, the site supports Latex formatting for formulas. Look, how beautiful your post became. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$ \csc x=  \frac{1}{\sin x}$$ 
or
$$ \csc x=  \frac{1}{\pm\sqrt{1-cos^2 x}}$$

Comment: Yeah, I forgot it, thanks for pointing me out!